# $cordovaFile.createDir replace attribute not working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have found that the replace attribute in the createDir method is not obeyed. When set to true and the file already exists I get error code 12 (PATH_EXISTS_ERR).

```
$cordovaFile.createDir("test", true).then(function (result) {
    console.log("Directory Created");
}, function(err) {
    //This line is being called when the file already exists
    console.log("Error creating directory: "+err);
});
```

If anyone has an idea as to a work around that would be great.

David

---

To be thorough, I have specified the following in the config.xml in order to specify the default file locations.

```
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Internal" />
<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library" />
```

Comment: Have you injected the $cordovaFile module?

Comment: Yes, the $cordovaFile module is properly injected, I also tested with phone gap build, both give the same result. It successfully creates the directory the first time and each following time returns the error.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem. I modifying createDir method within ng-cordova.js. like this:

```
createDir: function (dir, replaceBOOL) {
var q = $q.defer();

getFilesystem().then(
    function (filesystem) {
        filesystem.root.getDirectory(dir, {
            create: true,
            exclusive: replaceBOOL
        },
        function () {
            q.resolve();
        },
        function () {
            q.reject();
        });
    }
);

return q.promise;

},
```

It's Solved.

Comment: Sorry, but this didn't solve my problem, it calls q.reject() when replaceBOOL is true.

Comment: Also, the default createDir already returns a $q promise, so there should be no need to override the default functionality here.

Comment: I am thinking that the problem may be deeper into the cordova api, it seems as if the exclusive option is not working properly when calling the api directly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the work around that I came up with, it's unfortunate that this is necessary.

First add removeDir function to ng-cordova.js

```
removeDir: function(dir) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    getDirectory(dir, {create: false}).then(
        function(entry) {
            entry.removeRecursively(
                function(result) {
                  defer.resolve();
                },
                function(error) {
                  console.log("Error removing directory: "+error.code);
                  defer.reject(error);
                }
            );
        },
        function(error) {
          console.log("Error retrieving directory - "+dir+" : "+error.code);
          defer.reject(error);
        }
    );
    return defer.promise;
  },
```

Then check for the directory and remove it, if it is there, else just create the directory

```
$cordovaFile.checkDir("test").then(
    function(){
        console.log("Directory Exists");
        $cordovaFile.removeDir("test").then(
            function(){
                createDirectory();
            }
        )
    },function() {
        console.log("Directory Doesn't Exist");
        createDirectory();
    }
);
function createDirectory() {
    $cordovaFile.createDir("queuedItems/images/" + sightingId, true).then(function (result) {
        console.log("Directory Created");
    }, function (err) {
        console.log("Could not create directory for sighting");
    });
}
```

Comment: I won't confirm this as the solution for a while just incase someone else has a better solution.